# Why do I get permission denied error when configuring IPsec on Ubuntu?

Tags: ipsec

When I try to edit the `ipsec` tools I get the `permission denied` error.

```
$ /etc/ipsec.conf
bash: /etc/ipsec.conf:permission denied.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `sudo` privileges will need to use `sudo vi /etc/ipsec.conf` and enter your password.

If you aren't a `vi` fan, use any editor you want, such as a `nano` or `gedit`.

Answer (score 2):

The command `/etc/ipsec.conf` attempts to run `/etc/ipsec.conf` as a program or script. But it isn't an executable you wish to run--instead, it is a configuration file you wish to edit.

Happily, it does not have execute [permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) set on it, so this fails.

To edit a file, start with the program you wish to use to edit it, and then (after a space) supply the name of the file you want to edit. The general form of such a command is: *`editor file`*

As [bntser says](https://askubuntu.com/a/354377/22949), this file is [owned by root](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Superuser&redirect=no#Unix_and_Unix-like) so you must edit it as root. (That is *not* the cause of the "permission denied" message, though, which is from trying to execute a file that does not have executable permissions.) To do so, use [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html), or [`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gksudo.1.html).

To edit with a non-graphical editor, [use `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and provide the name of the editor. [`nano`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/nano.1.html) is easy to use. I recommend invoking it as `nano -w` for editing configuration files. This makes it so that when there's a line in the file that is wider (in number of characters) than your terminal, you scroll left and right to edit it. In other words, it disables ["soft" word wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Soft_and_hard_returns). Word wrapping can be confusing when editing configuration files, because unless you're quite familiar with the file's contents, you might not be sure where one line ends and the next begins.

```
sudo nano -w /etc/ipsec.conf
```

To open the file with a graphical editor like [`gedit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gedit.1.html) or [`leafpad`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/leafpad.1.html), [use `gksudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ipsec.conf
```

If you don't have `gksudo`, you can install the [gksu [image: Install gksu]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gksu) package to get it, or you an use `sudo -H` or `sudo -i`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/ipsec.conf
```

However, [you should avoid `sudo gedit`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application) without `-H` or `-i` (and similar commands with `gedit` replaced by the name of another graphical program).